# Second order differential equation with constant second member $-g$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve this differential equation : 
$$\ddot z(t)+A\dot z(t)=-g$$
where $g$ is constant. 
I know that the solution of : 
$$\ddot z(t)+A\dot z(t)=0$$
is $z(t)=\alpha + \beta e^{-At}$ but I can't find the particular solution...

Comment: Why not just choose a particular solution of the form $$z_p(t) = k t$$ Multiplying by $t$ accounts for the constant solution in the homogeneous solution. Then, substitute and solve for $k$.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake. I edit my equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u(t)=\dot z(t)$ then your ODE is of first order with respect to $u$:
$$\dot u(t)+A u(t)=-g$$
where the solution is $u(t)=\beta e^{-At}-\frac{g}{A}$ (the particular solution is easy to find here).

Finally, in order to find $z$, we integrate $u$ with respect to $t$:
$$z(t)=\int u(t)\,dt=\int\left(\beta e^{-At}-\frac{g}{A}\right)dt=-\beta e^{-At}-\frac{gt}{A}+\alpha.$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are arbitrary real constants.